# Does adding dependency to gradle in android studio while not using it at all affect apk size?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk, libraries

In a big project while former developers already worked on, you can find dependencies in `gradle` that doesn't have any usages at all.

Do those dependencies affect `apk` size? and how dependencies affect `apk` size, what if you're just using one method from a library, does this mean that all the library files attached to your `apk`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do library dependency increase size of APK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326600/do-library-dependency-increase-size-of-apk)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326600/do-library-dependency-increase-size-of-apk

Comment: What happens when the author of a dependency removes it such that the dependency can no longer work ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, unused dependencies do increase the apk size.

**Enabling**

> minifyEnabled true

can analyze all the bytecode and remove unused classes and methods.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      shrinkResources true
    }
  }
```

It is good to remove all the unused dependencies from gradle

Comment: What happens when the author of a dependency removes it such that the dependency can no longer work ? Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, author can remove dependency. In such case  if the project already contains the compiled code it won't effect the work flow of the project but if not then gradle will show error while syncing.



Error: Failed to resolve: "dependency name"

Answer (score 1):

> Do those dependencies affect apk size? and how dependencies affect apk size

Yes of course.
The dependencies are added in the final apk, so the classes and the resources are added and they increase the size of the apk.

> what if you're just using one method from a library, does this mean that all the library files attached to your apk.

Yes, all the library is attached.

There are some features in gradle to add a dependency removing the unused resources.

Comment: What happens when the author of a dependency removes it such that the dependency can no longer work ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes gradle dependency  definitely affects your apk size. if you are not using gradle dependency anywhere in the project then please remove the dependency

And even if you are using one mehtod from a library all files are attached to your apk. so to avoid this enable proguard tool with shrinkResource as true. This will obfuscate and  simply remove unused method in the library and reduce the apk size

Comment: does it matter if I enable it in both debug and release configuration?

Comment: Don't enable it in debug mode enable only in release mode since it take more time to build

Comment: What happens when the author of a dependency removes it such that the dependency can no longer work ? Is it possible ?

Comment: In that case  your gradle wont compile itself