# Why apk increased 2x in size on new version build.gradle 3.

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Could anyone explain how apk increases by 2x in size on the same project. What changed were the gradle versions in Android Studio. Built.gradle 2.2 -> 3.0.1 and Gradle 3.5 -> 4.

Due to this I had to enable Multidex.

Tks :)

Comment: you can try using ProGuard. It should shrink all unused methods

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Many thanks for the quick reply. I just wanted to know why it has increased so much. There must be something wrong.

Comment: probably syntax of some command changed, and it does not do something you expect it to do. Many possible reasons actually. You can check the changelog to know what exactly is changed

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko 
thanks man I'll take a look at the syntax

Answer (score 4):

In Android Studio go to **Build->Analyze APK...** and you can see what is consuming space in your .APK file

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I analyzed apk and strangely everything increased in size. And I did not update anything just the gradle :(

Comment: Look [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221828/does-adding-dependency-to-gradle-in-android-studio-while-not-using-it-at-all-aff) also, it could be that you have new dependencies in project that makes APK larger.